# How to clear memory on each execution?

Tags: php, memory, memory-limit

I have something like this:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

//require_once '../../tabkadeh/error_reporting.php';
function setName($name,$photoName, $new_file)
{
    var_dump($new_file);
    require_once 'files/lib/WideImage.php';
    require_once 'FarsiGD.php';

    $left = '+50';
    $top  = '+400';

    $bg = WideImage::load($photoName);
    //$final= $bg ->resize(400, 400);
    $final= $bg;
    $canvas = $final ->getCanvas();
    //$canvas->useFont('./Yekan.ttf', 200, $final->allocateColor(000, 000, 000));
    $new_name=(new FarsiGD)->persianText($name,'fa', 'normal');
    $canvas->useFont('./Ray-ExtraBlack.ttf', 40, $final->allocateColor(34, 84, 109));
    $canvas->writeText("left $left", "top $top",$new_name);
    $final->saveToFile($new_file);
}

$file = fopen("Main.txt", "r");
$i = 0;
$line_of_text = '';
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line_of_text .= fgets($file);
}
$myText = explode("\n", $line_of_text);
fclose($file);


$arrayCount = count($myText);
var_dump($myText);

for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++) {
    setName($myText[$x], './bgbg.jpg', './export/flower_stamp-'.$x.'.jpg');
}
```

This file : `Main.txt` contains lots of data (2000 lines of product name).

I've increased the memory limitation ; but when I run the script this only works from line 1 to line 250 or less! 
How can I clean up the memory for each photo generation?

Comment: Load one line from the file and process it. Then load the next! Dont load EVERYTHING into a BIG STRING and then make a array of it and then process each occurance

Comment: You can also add some `unset()` on variables when you're done with them. I don't really see 2000 rows of product names being that much though, unless you continuously run multiple instances of the same script at the same time, but that would most likely cause other issues (since all instances would write to the same file)

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly ; Could you show me how to do like this? I'm front-end developer and I don't know what to do!

Comment: Maybe saving all the data in a database would be better,

Comment: Basically just move the code into the `while (!feof($file)) {` loop so you call `setName()` everytime you load a line

Answer (score 1):

Load one line from the file and process it. Then load the next! Dont load EVERYTHING into a BIG STRING and then make a array of it then process each occurance of the array.

Once you do this you may well not need to increase the memory limit or the execution time.

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

//require_once '../../tabkadeh/error_reporting.php';
function setName($name,$photoName, $new_file)
{
    //var_dump($new_file);
    require_once 'files/lib/WideImage.php';
    require_once 'FarsiGD.php';

    $left = '+50';
    $top  = '+400';

    $bg = WideImage::load($photoName);
    //$final= $bg ->resize(400, 400);
    $final= $bg;
    $canvas = $final->getCanvas();
    //$canvas->useFont('./Yekan.ttf', 200, $final->allocateColor(000, 000, 000));
    $new_name = (new FarsiGD)->persianText($name,'fa', 'normal');
    $canvas->useFont('./Ray-ExtraBlack.ttf', 40, $final->allocateColor(34, 84, 109));
    $canvas->writeText("left $left", "top $top",$new_name);
    $final->saveToFile($new_file);
}

$file = fopen("Main.txt", "r");
$i = 0;
$line_of_text = '';
while ($line = fgets($file, 4096) !== false) {
    setName(trim($line), './bgbg.jpg', './export/flower_stamp-'.$i.'.jpg');
    $i++;
}

fclose($file);
```